# Create OpenLayers layer from GeoServer WFS

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs

I try to create a layer for a map using OpenLayers and get the data from my GeoServer setup (2.14.0).

http://host-310-1-fk:6081/geoserver/Aver/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Aver%3Aave_Flurstueck&maxFeatures=50

If I use the above link I get the features in XML, I tried the following to use the same data as features.

```
var wfs_bcd = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("ALKISTEST2", {
    strategies : [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol : new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        version : "1.1.0",
        url : "http://host-310-1-fk:6081/geoserver/wfs", 
        featurePrefix : "ave",
        featureType : "ave_Flurstueck",
        featureNS : "Aver",  // My namespace URI
        geometryName : 'geometrie',
        srsName : "EPSG:25833"
    })
})


wfsBB = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("ALKISTEST2", {
    strategies : [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
        protocol : new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        version : "1.0.0",
        url : "http://host-310-1-fk:6081/geoserver/ows?", 
        featurePrefix : "ave",
        featureType : "ave_Flurstueck",
        featureNS : "Aver",  // My namespace URI
        //geometryName : "GEOM", type "Geometry"
        srsName : "EPSG:25833"
    })
```

´´´

Both request return empty wfsBB.feature arrays. I don't know where to fix as it seems I tried everything.

Update1:
After having some conversation with Ian Turton in the comments I edited my layer-definition:

```
wfsBB = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("ALKISTEST2", {
    strategies : [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
        protocol : new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        version : "1.0.0",
        url : "http://acver1234.org", 
        featurePrefix : "Aver",
        featureType : "ave_Flurstueck",
        featureNS : "http://acver1234.org",  // My namespace URI
        geometryName : "geometrie",
        maxFeatures: 50,
        srsName : "EPSG:25833"
    })
```

So this is seems to be the relevant excerpt from the geoserver-logs, I get no error message but no features as well.

```
2021-08-24 14:44:14,498 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
    Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
    version = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = http://host-310-1-fk:6081/geoserver/
    query[0]:
        typeName[0] = {http://acver1234.org}ave_Flurstueck
    maxFeatures = 50
    outputFormat = GML2
    resultType = results
```

Update 2:
Apparently it is not working anymore, here is the excerpt from the geoserver-logs, for some reason there is a query part in it and the typenames etc. seem to be wrong.

The request/code is the same as above as I did not change anything.

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/08/26 14:52:40 | Request: getFeature
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/08/26 14:52:40 |     service = WFS
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/08/26 14:52:40 |     version = 1.0.0
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/08/26 14:52:40 |     baseUrl = http://localhost:6081/geoserver/
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/08/26 14:52:40 |     query[0]:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/08/26 14:52:40 |         filter = [ plis_id =     107315294000010 ]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/08/26 14:52:40 |         typeName[0] = {http://plis.org}invalid_geometry
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/08/26 14:52:40 |     outputFormat = GML2
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/08/26 14:52:40 |     resultType = results
```

Comment: I don't think your `feature_prefix` is correct - looks like it should be `Aver` - which would probably make the URI wrong too

Comment: @IanTurton How should the URI look like? If I change the feature_prefix? (Defintitely wrong, guess I changed that when I tried some things)

Comment: it should be whatever you put in the URI box of the workspace

Comment: So there I put some random Aver234.org, how should the URI look like then?

Comment: @IanTurton can you further elaborate on this?

Comment: It will need to match exactly what you put in that box, as that is what the XML parser is expecting

Comment: @IanTurton I changed the box to host-310-1-fk:6081/Aver234 and added my current request at the end of the question, still no results.

Comment: A URI is of the form `http://acver1234.org` - next thing to do is look in the log file and see what the error message is

Comment: So I changed some things and checked the geoserver-logs, there seems to be no error message but still no features were returned.

Comment: may be there are no features in your bounding box

Comment: But I did not specify a bounding box in the request

Comment: `strategies : [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()]` implies that you did - check the network tab to see what exactly is sent and returned

Comment: Ah thank you, I will check that later/tomorrow. Hopefully I finally get the results :D

Comment: Just to give an update: It is still not working, I do not even get anything in my geoserver logs by now even with the same code as yesterday.

Comment: heck the network tab to see what exactly is sent and returned

Comment: There is no request related to this for some reason, i think this might be because the request is run through a proxy. I will check soon if it replicates if I change the setup. Stilll updated my post with the current state/response